# Flex Lazy Binding

Tags: apache-flex, binding, lazy-loading

Inspired by the lazy loading abilities of Hibernate I wanted to make the model part of my Flex UI request data from the server only when necessary. I thought this would be as simple as adding a public accessor that only sends server requests when the variable is accessed.

```
public function get tab2AC():ArrayCollection
{
    if(_tab2AC == null){
        //Request data from server
    }
    return _tab2AC;
}
```

Problem is that Flex seems to access **all** bound variables on application launch, even if the referencing component has yet to be created. So even though the DataGrid with `dataProvider="{tab2AC}"` has yet to be created, the server request still goes out, thus defeating the "only when required" laziness.

I do not want to place the server request inside a creationComplete handler as I want to keep my UI model ignorant of view state and my view ignorant of server requests.

Interestingly, if I add an `Alert.show("anything");` inside the accessor, it works as desired.

UPDATE: Here is a full example. Set breakpoints and you'll see that Flex accesses both variables even though titleForScreen2 is not used by any created component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var _titleForScreen1:String;
        private var _titleForScreen2:String;

        public function get titleForScreen1():String {
            if(_titleForScreen1 == null){
                //Server Request
            }                   
            return _titleForScreen1;
        }

        public function get titleForScreen2():String {
            if(_titleForScreen2 == null){
                //Server Request
            }
            return _titleForScreen2;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:ViewStack>
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Screen 1">
        <s:Label text="{titleForScreen1}"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Screen 2">
        <s:Label text="{titleForScreen2}"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: "Problem is that Flex seems to access all bound variables on application launch, even if the referencing component has yet to be created. " I could use some context for this. What is the referencing component and what is the "Bound variable".  One of them must have been created for Flex to access it in some way.  If you showed more of your architecture/code perhaps we could explain that.

Comment: if you have a datagrid on your display tree which has a dataprovider, it will try to access the bound variable.  Please show more code as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you post the code where the dataGrid is? Also, can you post more of the code of the data class where the above getter resides? Are you using a custom binding event? You say "here is a full example," but I'm confused as to where here is actually supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't post full code in comments. See update to question.

Comment: I am not familiar with how NavigatorContent draws its children. Try using a mx Container, which defers instantiation of its children when the creationPolicy is set to "auto". I'll try to make time to dig through NavigatorContent over the weekend.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I swapped the NavigotorContent for a Container without any luck. Also added creationPolicy="auto" to both viewstack and container. I've also verified that a creationComplete handler does not get called until desired. It's so weird that the variable still gets accessed though (and actually multiple times). Also strange that adding an Alert.show statement inside the accessor  prevents it from being executed (called but not executed).

Comment: Would this do more what you want (http://www.jamesward.com/2010/10/11/data-paging-in-flex-4/)? If you started out with an empty AsyncListView that declares a length, rather than null, then when the datagrid goes to read the first element in the List, it should kick off your server call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, that's just the way it is. Since Flex evaluates bindings immediately, I have to delay bindings until creation in order to prevent premature evaluation. Seems like extra work to undo Flex's weird behavior, but that's just how it goes sometimes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
        import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher;

        private var _titleForScreen1:String;
        private var _titleForScreen2:String;

        public function get titleForScreen1():String {
            if(_titleForScreen1 == null){
                //Server Request
            }
            return _titleForScreen1;
        }

        public function get titleForScreen2():String {
            if(_titleForScreen2 == null){
                //Server Request
            }
            return _titleForScreen2;
        }

        public function updateLabel1(value:String):void {screen1Label.text = value;}
        public function updateLabel2(value:String):void {screen2Label.text = value;}

        public function bindLabel1():void {
            var changeWatcher:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(updateLabel1,this, "titleForScreen1");
        }

        public function bindLabel2():void {
            var changeWatcher:ChangeWatcher = BindingUtils.bindSetter(updateLabel2,this, "titleForScreen2");
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:ViewStack>
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Screen 1">
        <s:Label id="screen1Label" creationComplete="bindLabel1()"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Screen 2">
        <s:Label id="screen2Label" creationComplete="bindLabel2()"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bindings in flex are pretty stupid. More of a proof of concept than an actual optimized production quality feature. What's worse is that short of modifying the compiler, there's little you can do about it without having all sorts of verification logic in your getter or (perhaps more likely) some kind of interceptive layer that makes sure that expensive calls are only made when the UI state is meaningful. At that point however, you might as well do away with bindings altogether and just implement an active controller for a passive view.

I know this is a pretty lame answer, but it's true. I've been a flex developer for several years and have had a complicated relationship with its binding feature for just as long. As well, over all this time, the only thing that has changed in the binding implementation is the ability to do two-way bindings.

---

By the way, syntactically I'd use a regular method rather than a property for returning a promise. Properties are often read as synchronous and cheap(-ish) operations, whereas a method (especially one that returns a promise) would have more flexible connotations.

Comment: Agreed but I'm not sure I want to abandon them completely. Since Flex jumps the gun, I just have to wait to give it the gun.

Comment: Short of having a more complex facade that is able to queue the calls and fire them off when the time is right, I'm afraid you're SOL :(

Comment: My solution is to perform the bindings on creationComplete. Setting the bindings in AS is not as simple as in MXML but it seems to be doing the trick. If you have a moment, please take a look at my answer and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private var _titleForScreen1:String;
            private var _titleForScreen2:String;

            public function get titleForScreen1():String {
                if(_titleForScreen1 == null){
                    //Server Request
                }                   
                return _titleForScreen1;
            }

            public function get titleForScreen2():String {
                Alert.show("test");
                if(_titleForScreen2 == null){
                    //Server Request
                }
                return _titleForScreen2;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:ViewStack>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Screen 1">
            <s:Label text="{titleForScreen1}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Screen 2">
            <s:Label text="{titleForScreen2}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:ViewStack>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Breakpoints on lines 12 and 19, check out the stack trace during each, also you can pop open Binding and take a look at wrapFunctionCall (drop a breakpoint in there too).  So when it gets to lines 12 and 19, it hits them 2 times because of the preloader dispatching a complete event.  I put breakpoints in every file that the stack-trace showed the execution path moving through.  Unfortunately I couldn't find the point where it caused 2 calls to happen (must be in the parts I don't have the source for) it seemed every spot in the trace was only called once but I think the wrapFunctionCall was called twice during the period of those two executions.  The third one that happens is due to a call to doPhasedInstantation which calls down to execute on Bindings for all the children that have the systemManager, so it would seem somehow the components have a system manager even though they may have not yet been added to the stage or created.  Sorry I don't have a more concrete answer for why each of these has to happen but my guess is there's some good reason.

Ah yah almost forgot, also you'll see when the Alert is shown it causes an error but that error is captured in the wrappedFuncitonCall method in Binding.as

```
catch(error:Error)
    {
        // Certain errors are normal when executing a srcFunc or destFunc,
        // so we swallow them:
        //   Error #1006: Call attempted on an object that is not a function.
        //   Error #1009: null has no properties.
        //   Error #1010: undefined has no properties.
        //   Error #1055: - has no properties.
        //   Error #1069: Property - not found on - and there is no default value
        // We allow any other errors to be thrown.
        if ((error.errorID != 1006) &&
            (error.errorID != 1009) &&
            (error.errorID != 1010) &&
            (error.errorID != 1055) &&
            (error.errorID != 1069))
        {
            throw error;
        }
        else
        {
            if (BindingManager.debugDestinationStrings[destString])
            {
                trace("Binding: destString = " + destString + ", error = " + error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is not true, `tab2AC` getter is not accessed by Flex app on launch, as a proof here is the full application code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            private var _tab2AC:ArrayCollection;

            public function set tab2AC(value:ArrayCollection):void
            {
                _tab2AC = value;
            }

            [Bindable]
            public function get tab2AC():ArrayCollection
            {
                if(_tab2AC == null){
                    trace("THIS WILL NOT BE CALLED");
                }
                return _tab2AC;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

As you can see, the trace will not be triggered, so your problem seems to be coming from a call to that getter from somewhere in your app, to find it, put a break-point and then "Step return" when needed.

That being said, you should not implement the lazy loading this way directly in the getter as the service call is asynchronous.

Comment: -1 While the asynchronous comment is correct and important, you are completely ignoring the binding that the OP is having issues with. His application accesses the field on launch because it **is bound to something's dataProvider property**

Comment: You should learn to read before downvoting someone. I highlight the relevant part for you: _So even though the DataGrid with dataProvider="{tab2AC}" has **yet** to be created_ And when you are absolutely sure, then read again :)

Comment: Meaning that it is *on a secondary tab*, hence the name 'tab2AC', not that it doesn't exist in the application.

Comment: This is you supposing things, and trying to justify your action. Never-mind, I don't care, it is just not fair to act this way and after being shown that you are wrong, not admit it.

Comment: Since the data is bound, it's inconsequential that the service call is asynchronous. Whenever the server gets around to returning data, stuff gets updated. But yes, there is a DataGrid on a second tab that uses the ArrayCollection and even though the DataGrid hasn't been created, the ArrayCollection is still accessed for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. You made one assumption on the meaning of 'not created yet', I made another assumption. Mine turned out to be correct. I felt that your assumption was silly, wasted the time of the OP, and deserved a downvote. There's nothing to admit.

Comment: Well Gurtnamona then it is your fault I got downvoted! :) For the asynchronous part, it is important as you still have to return null when invoking services.
You should call the service on state change, it should be more reliable.
@Sam, downvoting on assumptions is not correct, but I suppose it is alright in your world. Peace.

Comment: I upvoted this, because Adnan is completely correct. If the DataGrid is totally not created yet, it is not calling the getter, binding or not. His suggestion of using the debugger is a good one, in the absence of actual code to look at.

Comment: For some reason my earlier comment about the "asynchronous nature of the call being inconsequential" did not show up. Of course it's consequential. You're returning a value right away. Unless you're dispatching your binding event again (to force the getter to be called again), the dataGrid (or whatever is calling the getter) won't know there's something to look at.

Comment: My architecture contains a static model who's responsible for server interaction and providing data to the view as requested. I am not using states. I just can't figure out why Flex is requesting data when not yet needed. Please see update with full example.

Comment: @Amy that is incorrect. The datagrid is not created yet the accessor is called. Of course I used the debugger (that's how I knew it was being called). Test it out.

Comment: Yes Amy, unfortunately it is true, Flex initializes the binding even if the datagrid is not created. I think it only happens if there is a state involved (non created content referencing the binding more precisely), without it, it is not called. That is why I suggested to implement the "lazy loading" on state change (or other event signaling the content should have been created) without binding at all. Data provider should be set on service response. Hope that help anyway and sorry about all this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Why not return back a new ArrayCollection when the variable is null, then set the source on the ArrayCollection when the server call returns?

Comment: This doesn't solve the fact that Flex calls the accessor prematurely (prior to creationComplete of the DataGrid that references the ArrayCollection). Also I stand by my comment that the asynchronous nature of the server call is moot. Since objects are pass by reference, when the call response updates the private AC it is also updating the AC feeding the DataGrid (as they are actually the same thing).

Comment: Right. That at least gives you something _to_ return, something that _will_ update.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just wonky behavior of the debugger, rather than what would happen in ordinary execution. If you put *any* logic in there that will enable you to determine that the function was called that doesn't tie into the debugger (such as setting the text on a label), then the getter doesn't get called. However, if you put a trace statement in there, the getter *does* get called.

The conundrum is how much do you want to depend on the idea that this is only going to happen in debugging, and how critical is it to get the real behavior while you are using the debug player?

Comment: The premature reference occurs independent of debugging. In my actual code I can see the server request occur even when not debugging.